# Row wise parallel Processing in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rstudio, convex-hull, extrapolation

I am working on large data sets, for which i have written a code to perform row by row operation on a data frame, which is sequential. The process is slow.
I am trying to perform the operation using parallel processing to make it fast.

Here is code

```
library(geometry)

# Data set - a
data_a   = structure(c(10.4515034409741, 15.6780890052356, 12.5581992918563, 
                       9.19067944250871, 14.4459166666667, 11.414, 17.65325, 12.468, 
                       11.273, 15.5945), .Dim = c(5L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", 
                       "3", "4", "5"), c("a", "b")))

# Data set - b
data_b   = structure(c(10.4515034409741, 15.6780890052356, 12.5581992918563, 
                       9.19067944250871, 14.4459166666667, 11.3318076923077, 13.132273830156, 
                       6.16003995082975, 11.59114820435, 10.9573192090395, 11.414, 17.65325, 
                       12.468, 11.273, 15.5945, 11.5245, 12.0249, 6.3186, 13.744, 11.0921), .Dim = c(10L, 
                       2L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), c("a", 
                       "b")))


conv_hull_1    <- convhulln( data_a, options = "FA")                        # Draw Convex Hull


test = c()


for (i in 1:nrow(data_b)){
  
  
  df = c()
  
  con_hull_all        <- inhulln(conv_hull_1,  matrix(data_b[i,], ncol = 2))
  
  df$flag             <- ifelse(con_hull_all[1] == TRUE , 0 , ifelse(con_hull_all[1] == FALSE , 1, 2))
  
  
  test                <- as.data.frame(rbind(test, df))
  
  print(i)
  
}

test
```

Is there any way to parallelize row wise computation?

As you can observe, for small datasets the computational time is really low, but as soon as i increase the data size, the computation time increases drastically.

Can you provide solution with the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strive to make fully reproducible examples. These should contain all the code to see the problem. Where do the functions `inhulln` and `convhulln` come from?

Comment: @AndrewChisholm , sorry my bad, edited the question. Do you have some solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the parameter to the `inhulln` function. This allows more than one row of points to be tested to be passed in.

I've tried the code below on a 320,000 row matrix that I made from the original data and it's quick.

```
library(geometry)
library(dplyr)
# Data set - a
data_a   = structure(
    c(
        10.4515034409741,
        15.6780890052356,
        12.5581992918563,
        9.19067944250871,
        14.4459166666667,
        11.414,
        17.65325,
        12.468,
        11.273,
        15.5945
    ),
    .Dim = c(5L, 2L),
    .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2",
                                         "3", "4", "5"), c("a", "b"))
)

# Data set - b
data_b   = structure(
    c(
        10.4515034409741,
        15.6780890052356,
        12.5581992918563,
        9.19067944250871,
        14.4459166666667,
        11.3318076923077,
        13.132273830156,
        6.16003995082975,
        11.59114820435,
        10.9573192090395,
        11.414,
        17.65325,
        12.468,
        11.273,
        15.5945,
        11.5245,
        12.0249,
        6.3186,
        13.744,
        11.0921
    ),
    .Dim = c(10L,
                     2L),
    .Dimnames = list(c(
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
    ), c("a",
             "b"))
)

conv_hull_1    <- convhulln( data_a, options = "FA")                        # Draw Convex Hull

#Make a big data_b
for (i in 1:15) {
    data_b = rbind(data_b, data_b)
}
In_Or_Out <- inhulln(conv_hull_1, data_b)
result <- data.frame(data_b) %>% bind_cols(InOrOut=In_Or_Out)
```

I use `dplyr::bind_cols` to bind the in or out result to a data frame version of the original data so you might need some changes for your specific environment.

Comment: i am well aware of this process. I asked this question because as soon as i am increasing dimensionality of data (instead of 2 columns if i am using 10 columns) the process is too slow. I wanted to test the potential of inhull function using parallel computation in my way. @andrew

Comment: Please can you post some representative data that allows the slow down to be observed? Without this, responders will make assumptions about dimensions. I assumed number of rows. Your new information reveals it's the number of columns that is important.

Comment: inhull function works fast for 5 columns and 6 million rows (computation time is ~2 minutes). As soon as i am increasing to 10 column and 6 million rows (computational time is too high, ~ 3-4 Days, my code is still running from last 3 days). @andrew

Comment: How long does 10 columns and 100,000 rows take?

Comment: It is also long (~3 hour). I think it has something to do with number of columns. I don't know how to get around this @andrew

Comment: How many CPUs are used during these 3 hours to process one chunk of 100,000? If it's all of them then the best you will ever get is going to be 3 hours x 60 chunks = 180 hours. If 1/6 of your CPUs are being used, this might reduce to 30 hours. Of course, these are back of the envelope calculations. It's worth thinking about this first before embarking on a solution that may never give a good result.